# How to get the name of a property as string?

Tags: java

I have a class `Car` that has a `Field` named `trunk`. How can I retrieve that name only with the property that is assigned to it and without any fixed `String`.
Something working like this fiction would be great:

```
System.out.println(new Car().getTrunk().getField().getName());
```

Output:

```
trunk
```

I don't want to use a fixed `String` to retrieve the `Field` and it's name because that would not refactor well. If I decide to rename from `trunk` to `boot` I want this to be handled completely by my IDE's refactoring tool.

UPDATE `Car` class:

```
public class Car{
    String trunk;
    // getters + setters
}
```

**BACKGROUND:**
I want to use [Primefaces' Dynamic Columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) for a CRUD-UI for several entities which uses a `columnTemplate` containig the names of the `Field`s/properties to be evaluated by `Expression Language`.

Comment: Could you please show your `Car` class?

Comment: Look up Reflection.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html

Comment: Seems to me that the property name is "trunk".  You know that because you said "getTrunk".  How would you not know the property name and still be able to reference it?

Comment: @Doorknob I looked into reflection but I don't see a way.

Comment: @Jigar Looks promising BUT uses strings from the beginning.

Comment: @Hot I know the property name but I need it in a String.

Comment: I suspect you are not approaching your problem correctly. Can you explain why you need this? A lot of refactoring problems are already handled well by current IDEs, especially renaming fields.

Comment: If you decide to rename `trunk` to `boot`, making it a `String` will *keep* your IDE from noticing it on a refactor. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: you can list all fields as well

Comment: @chrylis I don't need the `String` to be noticed but the method returning it.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I know I can list all fields, but I need only one. Else I would need to filter that list by a static variable: Won't refactor.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29

Comment: @MiserableVariable I will use the `String` that the desired method returns to be evaluated by Expression Language later on (see update concerning background of my question). So I need a way to retrieve that String, instead of typing it in manually (because the latter won't refactor).

Comment: @JigarJoshi I appreciate your efforts but please stop posting links without a comment. I see no way to use this considering the requirements I gave in the question.

Comment: sorry I misread your comment

Comment: It seems like the answer to your question is that no, you can't do this in an easily refactorable way. Maybe your requisites are too high. An IDE refactor doesn't always do everything for you.

Comment: @Radiodef I think you are right. :/

Comment: Sorry. And given that identifiers of fields and the like can be removed/replaced by the compiler it would seem if such a method existed to return those identifiers the returned value may not be particularly useful.

Comment: I am not familiar with Primefaces.

Comment: @Radiodef Sounds sensible. Still I am wondering how JSF's Facelet pages retrieve values from Expression Language like `#{carBean.myCar.trunk}`.

Comment: Okay, I get a glimpse... a new instance of `javax.el.Expression` is created that contains the EL-String and the value etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider introducing a enum holding all the properties (without values), for example

```
enum CarProperty {
 TRUNK, HOOD, WHATEVER;
}
```

and storing them in Car as EnumMap:

```
class Car {
 private Map<CarProperty, String> propsToValues = new EnumMap<>(...);
 public String getValue(CarProperty property) { ... }
}
```

property name could be accessed by

```
((CarProperty) anyPropery).toString()
```

And obviously it is easy to refactor

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But this is really an ugly workaround. Imagine it in a real project with a lot of classes to make use of it.

Comment: @Lester Agree, but as omarhry remarked, what you want to do is to break OOP principles which is always ugly.

Comment: @Lester by the way, if you use Intellij Idea to refactor your code, it will propose you to update getters and setters and other related code. Maybe this will help.

Comment: What OOP principle exactly is broken? I use [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) to reduce boilerplate code such as getters and setters - great tool.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good idea access to the property name.
With reflection you are breaking OOP principles.

getTrunk() not allways need to access a trunk property

You can have a

```
private Trunk trunk;//remember to change the TRUNK_FIELD
public static final TRUNK_FIELD = "trunk"
```

but... try to avoid this solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't see how this would refactor well.

Comment: Edited: use the public TRUNK_FILED, and when you refactor the Trunk trunk variable, change the "trunk" too. ¿That's not solve your problem?